# Finding and redacting Highlighted text in yellow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have the VBA code below (from another chat) which looks for highlighted and underlined text in a Word document and redacts it (i.e. replaces it with "x"s and highlights in black).

I would like to identify and redact only text highlighted in yellow.

It does not work on any document (complex or less complex).

```
Sub Redact()

' Redact Macro
' Macro to redact underlined text
' If redacted, text will be replaced by x's, coloured black and highlighted black

Dim OldText, OldLastChar, NewLastChar, NewText, ReplaceChar As String
Dim RedactForm As Integer
Dim flag As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

ReplaceChar = "x"

'Make sure to start at the beginning of the document
Selection.HomeKey wdStory
Do
 ' Find next underline with highlight
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
    Selection.Find.Highlight = True
    Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = ""
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    flag = Selection.Find.Execute
    If flag Then
        If Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then
            ' Create replacement string
            ' If last character is a carriage return (unicode 13), then keep that carriage return
            OldText = Selection.Text
            OldLastChar = Right(OldText, 1)
            NewLastChar = ReplaceChar
            If OldLastChar Like "[?*#]" Then NewLastChar = String(1, 13)
            NewText = String(Len(OldText) - 1, ReplaceChar) & NewLastChar

            ' Replace text, black block
            Selection.Text = NewText
            Selection.Font.ColorIndex = wdBlack
            Selection.Font.Underline = False
            Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdBlack
            Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        End If
    End If

Loop While flag

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Thanks for your help.

Best,
Carine

Comment: "It does not work" is not good starting point to help someone. You should describe what you expect and what is happening/what is missing. But: Most likely you want to remove `Selection.Find.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle`

Comment: I have run the script and it does not do what I wanted - looks for highlighted yellow text in a Word document and redacts it (i.e. replaces it with "x"s and highlights in black).

Comment: While what the code tries to do might in some circles be called redaction, it undoubtedly also messes with the document formatting, since a string of "x"s will rarely have the same overall character width as the text it replaces. One might just as well replace the whole of the unwanted text string with an elipsis.

Answer (score 0):

For some true redaction, try:

```
Sub RedactMe()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim wdPage As Page, wdRct As Rectangle, wdLine As Line, Rng As Range, sWdth As Single
For Each wdPage In ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Pages
  For Each wdRct In wdPage.Rectangles
    For Each wdLine In wdRct.Lines
      Set Rng = wdLine.Range
      With wdLine.Range
        If .Characters.Last.Text Like "[ " & Chr(160) & Chr(9) & "-" & Chr(13) & "]" Then
          .Characters.Last.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        End If
        With .Find
          .ClearFormatting
          .Replacement.ClearFormatting
          .Highlight = True
          .Wrap = wdFindStop
          .Text = ""
          .Replacement.Text = ""
          .Execute
        End With
        If .Find.Found = True Then
          If .End > Rng.End Then .End = Rng.End
        End If
        Do While .Find.Found = True
          If .InRange(Rng) = False Then Exit Do
          If .HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow Then
            .Fields.Unlink
            .HighlightColorIndex = wdBlack
            sWdth = .Characters.Last.Next.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) - _
              .Characters.First.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
            .Text = Chr(160) & Chr(160)
            .FitTextWidth = sWdth
          End If
          .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
          .Find.Execute
        Loop
      End With
    Next
  Next
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the new code. I have tried however I have an bug in the line "For Each wdLine In wdRct.Lines". Do you know why is it the case?

Comment: The code works fine for me... Tested with various scenarios before posting.

Comment: Indeed, it is working great on a simple text document. I have the error when I am inserting a figure however it still redacting it :-) The function doesn't work when I have a table of content formatted in word and sections.

Comment: A document that is being redacted probably shouldn't have a Table of Contents field. If you need to have one, the code should be modified so the outer loop starts after the Table of Contents page(s) - but then the Table of Contents would need refreshing to reflect any redacted headings in the document body. It's not clear what you mean about 'inserting a figure'. What kind of figure?

Comment: I've added a .Fields.Unlink line to the code, which should resolve any issues with fields occurring in the yellow-highlighted ranges.